# How to get user name during facebook canvas application authorization?

Tags: php, facebook-authentication, facebook-canvas

I am successfully able to authorize  my  canvas app using this code but I am only able to get the user id.I need user name,age friendlist also.Plz help me.

I used Print_r and get this

```
Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [expires] => 1366020000 [issued_at] => 1366012878 [oauth_token] => BAAFaFlrFWXYBADDEIui8rTtcEWldiZAGlHZB1mGSZoQ6E9fU9vkweYnx2jvj4SSDNRUd465YcAiz4hI3jlQlXLBmB0jVXZBeoAiSyO5P2TQoIQVt9SQRWVJEuTGtcyQzazZCi20MWhDqBsa1qgYWKloSRWOkKBdPDBZCI0exZA13Jygh73hsr9ldVvFy8ClgEb8jIZBblCArGT3lb7g [user] => Array ( [country] => pk [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) ) [user_id] => 100000
```

PHp code

```
 $app_id = "    xxxxxxxxx";

$canvas_page = "xxxxxxxx";

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), TRUE);

if(empty($data["user_id"])) {



    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");

} else {

    print_r($data) ;
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["age"]); //i tried this,but got undefined message?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do an API request or use FQL in order to get more information about the user. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ has examples that show you how to get the user's name with using the API method. And then [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) is the API documentation for FriendsList, and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist) is the FQL docs. Make sure you have the read_friendlists permission. Let me know if you have any questions :)

**Example with code:**
Follow the instructions at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ to install the PHP SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/ .

Then go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ and copy the first example into a file. Make sure to update the app id, app secret, and that your require_once is set to right location.

Then replace

```
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
```

with

```
try {
        //Get User Name
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        //Get User's Friends
        $friends_list = $facebook->api('/me/friends', 'GET');
        echo "<h1>Name: " . $user_profile['name']."</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Friends:</h2>"; 
        foreach ($friends_list['data'] as $friend)
        {
            echo $friend['name']."<br>";
        }
```

Comment: what specifically do you need illustrated by code? (any example code I would've used should be in the first link)

Comment: I want to echo the email and friendslist of the user,I tried scraching my head using above refrences,but of no vail.i ll be musch gratefull to u for the answer.

Comment: I answered your email question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014307/how-to-get-e-mail-when-logging-into-canvas-application-using-fb-graph/16016283#16016283). I answered there so that someone looking for the answer can find it more easily. Once again let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user endpoint in the Graph API sending a signed request, 
for example querying https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name
will give you the user name of the authenticated user.
See
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/
for reference.

I suggest you use the Facebook PHP SDK

you can get it from github and it makes things easier. I believe it has a basic example that does just what you want.

HTH