# How to get e-mail when logging into canvas application using fb graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-canvas, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the user  email when the user logged into my facebook canvas application using only fb graph api?I dont want to use facebook php sdk as I can not handle it with this code(Actually,I tried a lot but failed)Plz help

```
$app_id = "xxxxxxx";

$canvas_page = "xxxxxxxx";

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), TRUE);

if(empty($data["user_id"])) 
{
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} 
else 
{
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
    echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["email"]);   //i tried this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'email' field can be found within the FB API's `user` object, but only if you have explicitly asked for `email` permissions. There are many ways to request this permission,  e.g.

```
$param['scope'] = "email";
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($param);
echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
```

will print a login url that authorizes email permissions. You can then retrieve an email through the user object, as in the following example:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo "email: ".$user_profile['email'];
```

[**Note:** There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)